# Problems writing a 2D array into another C++

Tags: c++, arrays, copy

i want to copy the array "field" into copyField. 
I tried using a for loop but it gives me the following error:
main.cpp:123:20: error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript.
I know there is something like memcpy but i want to avoid it.
The code:

```
int main() {
    int j = 0;
    const char width = 16;
    const char height = 21;
    char field [height][width] = {
        "###############",
        "#             #",
        "# ## ### #### #",
        "# ## ### #### #",
        "#             #",
        "# ########  # #",
        "# #         # #",
        "# #  #####  # #",
        "# #  #####  # #",
        "# #         # #",
        "# #         # #",
        "#             #",
        "# ## ######## #",
        "# ## ######## #",
        "# ## ######## #",
        "#             #",
        "# ###     ### #",
        "# ########### #",
        "# ########### #",
        "#             #",
        "###############",
    };
    char copyField;


    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){

        copyField[i][j] = field[i][j];
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` is a type for a single character. 1 byte. You need another array.

Comment: `char copyField[height][width];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable copyField is not an array. I think you meant something as

```
char copyField[height][width];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char copyField[height][width];
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        copyField[i][j] = field[i][j];
    }
}
```

But why do you want to avoid `strcpy`?